# typescript: [Basics] function properties doesn't exist in type

Tags: typescript, types

Why `content`, `error` or `absolutePath` doesn't exist on `DirectoryState`?

```js
export type DirectoryState =
  | {
    content: Array<FileEntity>;
    absolutePath: string;
  }
  | {
    error: Error;
  };

export const setDirectoryState = (opts: DirectoryState): DirectoryState =>
  "error" in opts
    ? ({
      error: opts.error,
    })
    : ({
      content: opts.content,
      absolutePath: opts.absolutePath,
    });


// Why the errors here?
// vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
setDirectoryState({error: new Error('')}).error // error
setDirectoryState({content: [], absolutePath: ''}).absolutePath // error
setDirectoryState({content: [], absolutePath: ''}).content // error
```

I didn't understand why the errors are raising, any solution?

Comment: The `content` property (for example) of a value of a type `DirectoryState` is completely unknown, because object types in TypeScript aren't *sealed*; a value like `{content: 123, error: new Error()}` is a valid `{error: Error}`.  So checking `obj.content` doesn't really give you any information.  If you want  your `{error: Error}` not to  have a defined `content`, you need to [specify that explicitly](//tsplay.dev/NdjVQW) (but then you run into further issues).  Maybe you want a [discriminated union](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) instead.

Comment: Ahh, thanks, still facing another problem, I updated the question.

Comment: It's the same reason. The output is a `DirectoryState` so you can't arbitrarily index into it. Why would it be different?  It's not like `setDirectoryState` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function  like [this]https://tsplay.dev/N7PeRm); all the compiler knows is that a `DirectoryState` comes out of it, and has no more specific information.

Comment: great, solved thanks a million, I appreciate you.